# Oracle DB record accessible once only using NetFrameworkCore for Oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, usermanager

I have a simple web solution (incomplete) using NetFrameworkCore for Oracle.

See HomeController.CS & AspNetUser.CS -->

The issue is I have an AspNetUser record that was created in DB via Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager.
This record is accessible by finding by ID, managed to retrieve record.

However, on stopping the solution and doing a re-run (without creating new AspNetUser), I cannot retrieve the record via the ID.
Instead, a 500 error with invalid cast exception on Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetDateTimeOffset() is thrown.
The issue may not be table column related as re-creating the table allows the record to be accessible again albeit once as well.

What could be the issue then?
I apologize as I am new to Oracle and net core web.
Below are the links to the error and web solution.

Error 500: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjZf_PiMM9Arg6QLX9dfqkqu_Piepw

Solution: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjZf_PiMM9Arg6QKrT3AuP3QTJaQYQ?e=5lLU97

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve the issue of InvalidCastException. The current Oracle table was created manually without using EntityFrameworkCore tool.

After dropping the table and re-creating using the commands "add-migration " & "update-database", the table is accessible on subsequent reads.

The issue was with the column, LockoutEnd.

Changed from

```
"LockoutEnd" TIMESTAMP(7) NULL,
```

to

```
"LockoutEnd" TIMESTAMP (3) WITH TIME ZONE,
```